# using array_map to test values?

Tags: php, array-map

Is it possible to use array_map() to test values of an array? I want to make sure that all elements of an array are numeric.

I've tried both

```
$arrays = array(
         array(0,1,2,3 )
        , array ( 0,1, "a", 5 )
);

foreach ( $arrays as $arr ) {

        if ( array_map("is_numeric", $arr) === FALSE ) {
                echo "FALSE\n";
        } else {
                echo "TRUE\n";
        }
}
```

and

```
$arrays = array(
         array(0,1,2,3 )
        , array ( 0,1, "a", 5 )
);

foreach ( $arrays as $arr ) {

        if ( ( array_map("is_numeric", $arr) ) === FALSE ) {
                echo "FALSE\n";
        } else {
                echo "TRUE\n";
        }
}
```

And for both I get

```
TRUE
TRUE
```

Can this be done? If so, what am I doing wrong?

Note: I am aware that I can get my desired functionality from a foreach loop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

array_map returns an array. So it will always be considered 'true'. Now, if you `array_search` for FALSE, you might be able to get the desire effects.

From the [PHP.net Page](https://www.php.net/array_map)

```
array_map() returns an array containing all the elements of 
arr1 after applying the callback function to each one.
```

This means that currently you have an array that contains true or false for each element. You would need to use `array_search(false,$array)` to find out if there are any false values.

Answer (score 2):

I'm usually a big advocate of `array_map()`, `array_filter()`, etc., but in this case `foreach()` is going to be the best choice. The reason is that with `array_map()` and others it will go through the entire array no matter what. But for your purposes you only need to go through the array until you run into a value for which `is_numeric()` returns false, and as far as I know there's no way in PHP to break out of those methods.

In other words, if you have 1,000 items in your array and the 5th one isn't numeric, using `array_map()` will still check the remaining 995 values even though you already know the array doesn't pass your test. But if you use a foreach() instead and have it `break` on `is_numeric() == false`, then you'll only need to check those first five elements.

Comment: This is good advice, *But* Chacha says that array_map always returns an array, so the answer to the question "No, you can't use it how you want because it won't give you a single FALSE value if it encounters a non-numeric element". 

So you'd have to do foreach() anyway, in which case using break is very good advice :)

Answer (score 1):

You could use filter, but it ends up with a horrible bit of code

```
$isAllNumeric = count(array_filter($arr, "is_numeric")) === count($arr)
```

Using a custom function makes it a bit better, but still not perfect

```
$isAllNumeric = count(array_filter($arr, function($x){return !is_numeric($x);})) === 0
```

But if you were using custom functions array_reduce would work, but it still has some failings.

```
$isAllNumeric = array_reduce($arr,
                             function($x, $y){ return $x && is_numeric($y); },
                             true);
```

The failings are that it won't break when it has found what it wants, so the functional suggestions above are not very efficient. You would need to write a function like this:

```
function array_find(array $array, $callback){
    foreach ($array as $x){ //using iteration as PHP fails at recursion
        if ( call_user_func($callback, array($x)) ){
            return $x;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

And use it like so

```
$isAllNumeric = array_find($arr, function($x){return !is_numeric($x);})) !== false;
```

Comment: A nice summing up of the possibilities, and an even nicer extension to PHP!

Answer (score 1):

i have two tiny but extremely useful functions in my "standard library"

```
function any($ary, $func) {
   foreach($ary as $val)
      if(call_user_func($func, $val)) return true;
   return false;
}

function all($ary, $func) {
   foreach($ary as $val)
      if(!call_user_func($func, $val)) return false;
   return true;
}
```

in your example

```
 foreach ( $arrays as $arr )
    echo all($arr, 'is_numeric') ? "ok" : "not ok";
```

Comment: Those look handy, stereo! Pursuant to Jordan's comments, would you see a value in adding a `break` statement to the `any()` function?

Comment: In this case no, since return stops the execution much like break does.

Answer (score 0):

**A more elegant approach IMHO**:

```
foreach ($arrays as $array)
{
 if (array_product(array_map('is_numeric', $array)) == true)
 {
  echo "TRUE\n";
 }

 else
 {
  echo "FALSE\n";
 }
}
```

This will return true if all the values are numeric and false if any of the values is not numeric.